# What does "second base" refer to?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In *Bombshell* (2019), Gretchen complains about Fox CEO Steve Rogers to her attorneys:

> Gretchen: Then he took me off the show.
>
> Niel Mullen: But gave you your own.
>
> Gretchen: Well, in the afternoon dead zone. I mean, it was a demotion
> and we both knew it. Even though I did increase the ratings by 15%.
> He moved me to **second base**.

What does "second base" refer to?

Comment: CEO Steve Rogers? Captain America got dark in this timeline!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It’s only common if you come from one of the many, many countries where baseball is a popular sport (which at latest count is, at most, five).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Gretchen is making [a baseball metaphor](https://littleballparks.com/baseball-positions-ranked-by-difficulty/). Second baseman is a difficult position with plenty of responsibility but also fraught with hardship. It's a far less glamorous position than First baseman and less important than the Third base 'hot corner'.

She's saying that despite the apparent promotion (running her own show) it was also, in many ways, a demotion. Going from second fiddle on a primetime show to presenting in a dead slot is akin to being called up to a big league baseball team but then being asked to play in this thankless (and [undervalued](https://www.thedrummeyangle.com/post/where-was-the-monetary-value-positionally-during-the-2023-mlb-season)) position.

She clearly equates 2B with failure, not success.

> **GRETCHEN (V.O.):** *Back in Minnesota, before I was famous, before I graduated summa cum laude from Stanford, before I was Miss America, I played second base in our sixth-grade softball league.*
>
> **GRETCHEN (TO CAMERA):** ***I hate second base.***

Comment: "*It's a far less glamorous position than First Base*": disagree (like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_baseman) does too -> "*Due to these requirements, second base is sometimes a **primarily defensive position in the modern game**, but there are hitting stars as well. Second base is often referred to as the "**Keystone**". This is due to its position on the infield at the top of the diamond, similar to the keystone block in architecture.*"). A keystone **is** very important. Well, not in that channel though...

Comment: @OldPadawan - Important but less glamorous. Hard work for less reward, perhaps.

Comment: @OldPadawan Gretchen herself literally says it’s a demotion. Regardless of how Wikipedia views second base, Gretchen does not think it’s as good as whatever metaphorical position she was playing before.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Also her experience is from childhood games. Wikipedia is talking about professional baseball in the 2000s

Comment: I'm not a baseball fan, but aren't the outfielders the "unglamorous" positions? When I was a kid and not much of an athlete, that's where I always ended up.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, but she played second base in the past. Maybe she sees that as the 'bad position' because of her personal experience.

Comment: @OldPadawan Try searching "baseball positions ranked". Most lists have 2nd base near the bottom. Or just watch a baseball game -- 1st base and shortstop (Pete Rose's position!) see more action.

Comment: First base is far from a glamorous position. The slower and less athletic players (note that less athletic does not mean less powerful as many tend to be home run hitters) are usually at first base since they don't have to move that much.

Comment: @OldPadawan Some interesting statistics here suggest that second base is indeed among the lowest paid positions - it also appears undervalued in that spending more on an outfielder (among the highest-paid players) isn't correlated with more wins, but spending more on 2B is: https://www.thedrummeyangle.com/post/where-was-the-monetary-value-positionally-during-the-2023-mlb-season

Comment: @Barmar Only in little league, because fewer balls are hit to the outfield (ignoring the ones that roll past infielders). Once batters start getting more proficient and actually hitting fly balls and line drives to the outfield, the outfielders have the opportunity to showcase their athleticism more, as they have more ground to cover to make plays.